# Any PowerShell Command to Restart WebRole

Tags: powershell, azure

Is there any PowerShell Command to restart the WebRole or Worker Role . Please let me know

-Mahender

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking at Windows Azure PowerShell Cmdlets, the Command you want to use is Reset-AzureRoleInstance (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152835.aspx). If you're looking for 3rd party Cmdlets, you can check out Cerebrata's Azure Management Cmdlets as well. The Cmdlet to use there is "Restart-Role" (http://www.cerebrata.com/Products/AzureManagementCmdlets/Details.aspx?t1=0&t2=3)

Hope this helps.